# Signalr Unexpected Connection Inactivity Timeout

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

These are the configuration items the signalr server has

```
 GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
 GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
```

There has never been any inactivity in production for more than 3 years with this setup. It is a self hosted signalr server running as a windows service, and there are evidences that both the client application's and the server's processes are running after the timeout exception that is received in the client. ie No crashes. The client is another windows service running on the same machine as the server. The exception is

```
System.TimeoutException: The client has been inactive since 26/03/2018 07:00:12 and it has exceeded the inactivity timeout of 00:01:10. Stopping the connection.
```

Given the above are all that needed to conclude that the keep-alive messages should be sent every 5 seconds by the client, This is totally unexpected, Is this a known bug . as per the docs, the keep alive timeout is not more than 1/3 of the disconnection timeout. The other puzzling information from the error message is that the inactivity timeout is 00:01:10 which does not match up with anything (neither of default or the configured timeouts).

Am I missing something obvious ?